# Azure Dev ops variable scope

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When deploying release using Azure Dev Ops, the variable value is preserved between two stages instead of being overwritten as expected.

I am using azure dev ops to deploy data factory with its resources to different environments

- Test Environment
- UAT Environment

I have 2 variable groups defined in "Library" respectively for each stage of deployment

- Test-config and
- Uat-config

Both of those have a variable by name **varDataFactory** - to keep the data factory name
When linking the variable group in the pipeline "Variables" tab, I specify the stage at which i am expecting it to execute against.
[image]

So, the variable **varDataFactory** is expected to have different value at each stage.
Basically the first stage executes, creating the Test Data Factory, but then when UAT stage deploys, it "sees" the "varDataFactory" with its old value - the one for the "test".

And I do not know why, and what to do about it. Especially, since I have another pair of variable groups for Key vaults (2 different vaults for 2 environments) and those get in just file. Please, help !!

Comment: Please check if @kuldeep's answer works.

Comment: I resolved an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have 2 different configuration groups for 2 different stages, then I don't understand what do you mean by overwriting.

I tried this with a simple command line task in release pipeline with below configurations:

- Variable Group: test-config, Variable name: varDF, value: testdatafactory
- Variable Group: uat-config, Variable name: varDF, value: uatdatafactory

Pipeline variable Configuration:
[image]

Below are the outputs for echo$(varDF) command in test and UAT stages:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I found that at some point, in my ADO Pipeline, the variable group scope had both of the stages selected (By accident??)  So it was correct to be "stage scoped", but since both stages were selected .. i suppose it could have been picking the first one and then defaulting to it.  As I fixed that my issue is resolved